# Symfony 3 - I can not properly position my checkbox list

Tags: php, css, symfony, styles

I have a TypeUser entity and a Packages entity.
I have a ManyToMany relationship between these two entities, which allows me to add a package by linking it to one or more types of users through types that are in the form of checkbox.

Only when I go to my page to add a package, the list of checkbox is displayed but the first letter is cut by the box, and I can not manage to make sure it is well put

[image]

**new.html.twig :**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    <h1>Paquet creation</h1>
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{form_widget(form)}}

    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Ajouter"/>
    <a href="{{path('paquets_index')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Retour</a>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

The base.html.twig stylesheet :

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/baner.css') }}">

<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Can someone help me please ?

If I remove my CSS on my base.html.twig, my checkbox are correctly insered (but without CSS)

Comment: Nobody can help me ? :(

Comment: Up, I edited my post. Really, nobody know how I can resolve my problem ?

Comment: it's a css problem. you should check which css either makes the right margin/padding of the checkbox negative, or the left margin/padding of the "label". it really hasn't anything to do with symfony or php per se. try right-clicking on the label in the browser and select "inspect element" or something similar and look at the css. you really should learn how to debug this. there might be a trivial solution, there also might be a lot of head scratching ...